# Member names Cannot be the same as their enclosing type Unity 3D

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I dont really know why i get the Error on the Proccessing line.

I get the error on  `public static net_events.net_event net_event_proccess(net_events.net_event main)`

makes to me no sense because i defined all namespaces.

```
namespace net_events
    {
        class net_event
        {
            public string event_name;
            public object[] args;

            public void add(object mm)
            {
                object[] bkk = args;
                args = new object[args.Length + 1];
                for (int i = 0; i < bkk.Length; i++)
                    args[i] = bkk[i];
                args[args.Length] = mm;
            }

            public Action procc;

            public net_event(string eve, Action proc)
            {
                event_name = eve;
                procc = proc;
            }

            public net_event()
            {
            }
        }

        class net_event_proccess
        {
            private static List<net_events.net_event> events = new List<net_events.net_event>();

            public static net_events.net_event net_event_proccess(net_events.net_event main)
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < events.Count; i++)
                    if (events.ElementAt(i).event_name == main.event_name)
                        return events.ElementAt(i);

                return main;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: You defined a method called `net_event_proccess` within the `net_event_proccess` class.. "Member names Cannot be the same as their enclosing type". Give it a different name...

Comment: Thanks, well i code a lot in c# but i didnt even thought about that it collide with the classname. If you post it as answer i would upvote!